# Temp tables: CREATE vs. SELECT INTO

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, temp-tables

I've searched and found [this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables) about temporary tables in SQL Server because I've met a line in one of our stored procedures saying:

```
SELECT Value SomeId INTO #SomeTable FROM [dbo].[SplitIds](@SomeIds, ';')
```

I know that `#SomeTable` is stored in `tempdb` as a temporary table. However, I don't understand why we don't have to use `CREATE TABLE #SomeTable` first as it is written in the mentioned article. Our code is working fine, I just don't get why it is enough to use `SELECT ... INTO #SomeTable`. What would be the consequence when I add `CREATE TABLE #SomeTable` at the beginning? Would we get any differences in performance? Would the table be stored at another location?

Comment: Because that syntax is explicitly For creating and populating at the sane time.  You could Choose to create the range first, but then your insert statement needs to change to `insert into #temp select....`.  Essentially the answer is; because SELECT INTO creates temp tables, whereas INSERT INTO does not.  *(P.S.  If you create the table first you have more control; specifying Primary Key, etc, but then you CAN'T use SELECT INTO, you have to change to INSERT INTO.)*

Comment: @MatBailie This is what I was asking for. Please post it as answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Select ... into [table]` uses the properties of the dataset generated from the `Select` statement to create a temporary table and subsequently fill the table.

The alternative to using `Select ... into [table]` is to use a `Create Table` statement followed by an `Insert Into` statement. Explicitly creating the table offers more control and precision.

Using a `Select ... into [Table]` may seem like a no-brainer, but there are situations where `Select ... into [Table]` can be problematic.

For instance, when you are going to create a temporary table and insert additional rows at a later time, using the `Select ... into [Table]` syntax can cause problems, especially with string-based and nullable fields.

As an example of the limitations of the `Select ... into [table]`, the script below creates a temporary table with two fields, `First_Name` and `Last_Name`. Next, an `Insert` statement attempts to add another record to the temporary table, but fails as the values would be truncated.

```
Select 'Bob' as First_Name
    , 'Smith' as Last_Name
Into #tempTable;

Insert into #tempTable (First_Name, Last_Name)
Select 'Christopher' as First_Name
    , 'Brown' as Last_Name;
```

The script fails because the `Select ... into [table]` statement creates a table equivalent to the following script:

```
Create Table #tempTable (
    First_Name varchar(3) Not Null
    Last_Name varchar(5) Not Null
);
```